# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt while creating INI file

Tags: c#, ini

I have to use INI file in my project to store some data in the end. So i made a class in my project with different namespace. Now when i try to execute my project, i am getting this error. I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express. My code is:

```
namespace Ini
{
    public class IniFile
    {
        public string path;

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
            string key,int val,string filePath);
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
                 string key,string def, StringBuilder retVal,
            int size,string filePath);

        public IniFile(string IniPath)
        {
            path = IniPath;
        }
        public void IniWriteValue(string Section, string Key, int Value)
        {
            WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, this.path);
        }
        public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key)
        {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
            int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp, 255, this.path);
            return temp.ToString();

        }
    }

}
```

And I am using this in my main project..
`using Ini; (in namespace)`   and

```
IniFile MyIni = new IniFile("D:\\Database.ini");
 MyIni.IniWriteValue("ProductBase", "Key", 1);
```

(in my code)

Comment: The docs have this to say: "This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Applications should store initialization information in the registry." Maybe use an API that doesn't require calling `kernel32.dll`? Seems odd to me in a regular app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and on [p/invoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.writeprivateprofilestring), `WritePrivateProfileString()` has four string parameters, so change your definition to

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
        string key, string val, string filePath);
```

and the usage to

```
public void IniWriteValue(string Section, string Key, int Value)
{
    WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value.ToString(), this.path);
}
```